# Coverage tools, check what files haven't been covered - affected by tests

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, istanbul

I'm using istanbul as a coverage tool, but it shows covered only those lines of code that was affected by test, how can I know what files weren't affected by test flows ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? You answered yourself already. Everything not highlighted by istanbul is not covered by your tests.

Comment: Sure, but I need a way to see the difference, so I need to match the project structure against istanbul report, is there any tool for that? I mean folders where actual coverage is 0%

Comment: I don't think Istanbul provides anything like that unfortunately. I think your best bet is to manually compare the list of files covered by Istanbul with your full project structure, and see the differences.